# Wordpress custom rewrite rules not working

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to add a simple custom Wordpress rewrite rule but somehow I don't get this working.

This URL

http://www.gewerbesteuer.de/steuer/muenchen 
should call this

http://www.gewerbesteuer.de/index.php?pagename=gewerbesteuerhebesaetze&loc=muenchen.

So I want to call a page, which displays tax rates for a certain city, the city should be in the url as the last part.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%loc%', '([^&]+)'); 
    add_rewrite_rule('steuer/([^/]+)', 
        'index.php?pagename=gewerbesteuerhebesaetze&loc=$matches[1]', 'top');    
    flush_rewrite_rules();    
}

function query_vars($query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'loc';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag');
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars' );
```

The rewrite rule is working but the parameter (in this case loc) is not picked up. Even if I hardcode the rewrite rule with a certain city like

```
add_rewrite_rule('steuer/([^/]+)', 
    'index.php?pagename=gewerbesteuerhebesaetze&loc=muenchen', 'top');
```

it still doesen't pick up the value of the loc parameter. I also noticed that the $matches array is empty and doesn't contain any values.
I went through all the docs at wordpress and the questions here, but couldn't find the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks

Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this and see if this makes any difference?

**Edited**

I have changed the paramter in the rewrite rule from "`pagename`" to "`page_id`" - I am assuming its `2207` as thats what it said from looking at the body class on your website's page.

I also removed `flush_rewrite_rules()` from the `custom_rewrite_rules_tags` function, can you try this now then go to Options > Permalinks and re-save again.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules_tags() {
    global $wp_rewrite;  
    add_rewrite_tag('%loc%', '([^&]+)'); 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'steuer/([^/]+)', 
        'index.php?page_id=2207&loc=$matches[1]', 
        'top'
    );        
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules_tags');

function custom_query_vars($query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'loc';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I added this and it's still the same.

Comment: No problem, have you tried the usual trivial stuff - re-saving permalinks in Options > Permalinks ?

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Really thanks for your effort! I tried that and it's still not working.